# placing listview inside constraintlayout

Tags: listview, android-constraintlayout

There is a listview inside constraint layout, in listview there is a edittext whenever the user starts to enter vales in edittext and keypad opens then listview does not scrolls correctly and also there is button below listview it also come above the listview and above the keypad.

I am not getting how to solve it, here is the screen shot of ui page [click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obnNB.png)

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I got the answer, before i given constraint from listview to button after I changed constraint from button to listview this what the answer is.

Comment: Okay great! Happy learning :)

Comment: Tx for response.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got Answer for my question, before I given the constraint from listview to button after I changed the constraint from button to listview, and this is the solution.